# WSO2: Is there a way to customize devportal and publisher in source code?

Tags: reactjs, wso2, jsx, wso2-api-manager

I downloaded the WSO2 API Manager source code, and I want to customize some of .jsx files that it has. But there aren't any .jsx files.
I know that there is a way to customize devportal and publisher but, I want to work on its source code. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the source files in the APIM zip file. If you go to the location wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps, you can find the portals such as publisher, admin and devportal.

If you go to the location wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devportal/source/src, then you can find the devportal source code.

If you want to override you can place the relevant files in wso2am-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/devportal/override/src. Then it will override the existing portal UI.

More information can be found in [1].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/advanced-ui-customization/#advanced-ui-customization

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know these ways but, I download the source code from git from here:  https://github.com/wso2/product-apim, and there weren't any .jsx files.

Comment: You can find the code in https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps

Comment: Another question that I encounter is what is the difference between both source codes. What does each source code do?

Comment: Both have the same code. If you want to customize the UI for 4.1.0, use the code in the zip file. The apim-apps repo has the updated content.

Comment: But the codes are not the same in these sources: https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps and https://github.com/wso2/product-apim

Comment: Yes, it is not the same. WSO2 API Manager has three main repos. 1. APIM-apps: Host the React portal apps, 2. carbon-apimgt: Core modules are developed here. 3. Product-apim: Product build is happening here. It takes all the features in apim-apps and carbon-apimgt and build the product

Comment: Thank you for your response. You mean if I want to change something I should develop three of them. for example, if I want to change the dev portal in react that is in apim-apps, I should change Product-apim or not?

Comment: Most easiest option is to use the override option in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/advanced-ui-customization/#advanced-ui-customization. Otherwise you can do the changes in apim-app repo and link the source version in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/master/pom.xml#L1272